# Visual studio 2017 - Not able to restore Nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, I created a ASP.NET Web API project and it was working fine.

Today I got a new clone and when I tried to restore my packages, it keeps showing me this error

[image: error screenshot]

I have tried the following

1. Restarted Visual Studio as administrator
2. Rebooted PC
3. Disabled firewall settings
4. Disabled antivirus
5. Checked the port too, which is not being used

Nothing seems to work. Has anyone faced a similar issue? Is there any alternative way?

Comment: @Igor No, i have tried that

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your PC and executing the restore immediately after reboot?

Comment: yes i did that tooo

Comment: It's really frustrating , the same solution works with vs2015

Comment: Just some ideas for what else you could do: Check your nuget configuration file both in your solution and your global version, maybe you will see something there. You can also try to re-install nuget or replace the config with the default.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, could you open the link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/ in your browser directly? Besides, can you find this package via NuGet Package Manager UI? It seems the socket is held by some process. Use netstat -o to find which one and try to restart the “TCP/IP stack”, run CMD as administrator, type “netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt” to reset TCP/IP.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT yes opening in browser works! i managed to fix it by opening the solution in vs 2015 and then in 2017

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. You can write your workaround as a answer, and mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an issue related to Visual Studio 2017, I managed to resolve this by opening the solution in visual studio 2015.

Again by opening in 2017, this is the solution for now. If anyone comes up with a better solution it will be great.